# Summing a column gives null in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following sql statement that calculate the sum of the column:

```
 select coalesce(SUM(cdin_ActMortgageAmnt),0) 
 from CDIndex,company  
 where  comp_companyid=cdin_companyid and comp_idcust like '%10319%' 
 and cdin_Deleted is null and cdin_startunstufdate is not null 
 and cdin_Status='InProgress'
```

gives me the output like this:

[image]

I tried to convert it to LINQ like this:

```
var sumation = (from com in db.Companies
                join cd in db.CDIndexes on com.Comp_CompanyId equals cd.cdin_CompanyId
                where
                    cd.cdin_Status == "InProgress" &&
                    cd.cdin_startunstufdate == null &&
                    cd.cdin_Deleted == null
                select new {
                    sum = cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt 
                }
               );

var summ = sumation.Sum(x => x.sum);
```

When I put tracePoint beside var `summ` in debug mode it gives me null when i point to it.

What is the problem?

Comment: When you "point to it," is that `var summ...` line the active line, or have you already stepped over it when you observe `null`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @KennethK. What i do excactly is press (F5), the trace point change to yellow arrow so the debugger hit the `var summ` so that i press (F11) to step one line then i point to `var summ` it shows summ | null

Comment: Compare: `cdin_startunstufdate is not null` and `cd.cdin_startunstufdate == null`. And you're not even trying to filter by `comp_idcust`. Your 2 queries (SQL and LINQ) are different totally.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you very much i handle the two queries to be the  same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query is appropriate your sql query

```
     var sumation =db.Companies.Join(db.CDIndexes,
                                        com=>com.Comp_CompanyId,
                                        cd=>cd.cdin_companyid,
                                        (com,cd)=>new {com,cd})
                                   .Where(x=>x.com.comp_idcust.Contains("10319") && x.cd.cdin_Status== "InProgress" &&
                                          cd.cdin_startunstufdate != null &&
                                          cd.cdin_Deleted == null)
                                   .Select(x=>new 
                                   {
                                      sum=x.cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt ?? 0
                                   }).ToList()
```

Comment: Close, but you've reversed `com=>com.Comp_CompanyId, cd=>cd.cdin_companyid,`, and the `.ToList()` isn't required.

Comment: @RobertMcKee how I've reversed ?

Comment: It should be `cd=>cd.cdin_companyid, com=>com.Comp_CompanyId,` (inner key selection, then outer key)

Comment: you reversed the statements on @RobertMcKee answer, the only addition is your select, it doesn't make sense. Copy & paset

Comment: @Zinov He actually posted his answer before I posted mine, so he didn't copy/paste from me.  It's a good answer, just a few minor issues.

Comment: @Zinov I writed before RobertMcKee. look at answered time

Comment: @RobertMcKee there aren't a few minor issues. You said things is unimportant

Comment: Well except that the inner query doesn't have a field called `Comp_CompanyId` and will blow up (The outer query has the field `Comp_CompanyId`).  And the `.ToList` will cause the lazy execution to stop, where removing it will allow the datasource to do the `.Sum`, so it's a performance issue.

Comment: I didn't saw the post time of your answer. Sorry. About the performance of the query @RobertMcKee is right, once you call ToList() the query is executed, that means that the Sum statement is done in memory instead of the server side ;)

Answer (score 2):

On your case you are using coalesce(SUM(cdin_ActMortgageAmnt),0) because some values of cdin_ActMortgageAmnt can be null and you are giving the default value of 0, you need to do the same in your final query. Something like this when you do the select

```
cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt ?? 0
```

Comment: `      select new
                       {
                         cddd=  cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt==null?0: cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt
                       };`

does this solve the problem of null values?

Comment: that just gives you a default value for cdin_ActMortgageAmnt, on this case 0 or the value in case and your query. If you are still getting null is because the data doesn't meet the criteria you specified. Also your like statement should be translated using Contains comp_idcust.Contains("10319")

Comment: The coalesce isn't the problem, because the Sum will just ignore null values, so it isn't necessary to make sure the nulls are converted to 0 beforehand.  It's likely that the problem is his query looking for din_startunstufdate == null instead of != null like his SQL is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
var summ = db.Companies.Join(
    db.CDIndexes,
    cd => cd.cdin_CompanyId,
    com => Comp_CompanyId,
    (com, cd) => new { com, cd })
  .Where(z=>z.com.comp_idcust.Contains("10319")) // Added "LIKE"
  .Where(z=>z.cd.cdin_Status == "InProgress")
  .Where(z=>z.cd.cdin_startunstufdate != null) // Reversed your condition
  .Where(z=>z.cd.cdin_Deleted == null)
  .Sum(z=>z.cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt);
```

You can also combine all the Wheres together, but I prefer not to in most cases like this:

```
var summ = db.Companies.Join(
    db.CDIndexes,
    cd => cd.cdin_CompanyId,
    com => Comp_CompanyId,
    (com, cd) => new { com, cd })
  .Where(z=>z.com.comp_idcust.Contains("10319") // Added "LIKE"
    && z.cd.cdin_Status == "InProgress" 
    && z.cd.cdin_startunstufdate != null // Reversed your condition
    && z.cd.cdin_Deleted == null)
  .Sum(z=>z.cd.cdin_ActMortgageAmnt);
```

Comment: Also, Companies should have a navigation property to CDIndexes in your model, which would make this query very simple.